# ReadTimeout error when downloading images on AWS EC2 but not locally

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, request, timeoutexception

I have a Python script to download an image from a URL and upload it to AWS S3. This script works perfectly when I run it on my local machine. However, when I deploy and run the same script on an AWS EC2 instance, I encounter a `ReadTimeout` error.

The error I'm receiving is as follows:

```
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.net-a-porter.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=100)
```

Below is the relevant part of my code:

```py
import requests
import tempfile
import os

def upload_image_to_s3_from_url(self, image_url, filename, download_timeout=120):
    """
    Downloads an image from the given URL to a temporary file and uploads it to AWS S3,
    then returns the S3 file URL.
    """
    try:
        headers = {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36",
            'Accept': 'image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8'
        }
        # Request the image
        response = requests.get(image_url, timeout=download_timeout, stream=True, headers=headers)
        response.raise_for_status()
        
        # Determine the content type
        content_type = response.headers.get('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg')  # Default to image/jpeg

        # Create a temporary file
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as tmp_file:
            # Write the response content to the temporary file
            for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=8192):
                tmp_file.write(chunk)
            
            # Now that we have the image locally, upload it to S3 with the correct content type
            file_url = self.upload_image_to_s3(tmp_file.name, filename, content_type)

        # Optionally, delete the temporary file here if you set delete=False
        os.unlink(tmp_file.name)

        return file_url
    except requests.RequestException as e:
        raise Exception(f"Failed to download or upload image. Error: {e}")

# Example URL causing issues
image_url = "https://www.net-a-porter.com/variants/images/1647597326276381/in/w1365_a3-4_q60.jpg"
```

This issue occurs when trying to download an image from `www.net-a-porter.com`. The timeout is set to 120 seconds, which I assumed would be more than enough.

What I've tried so far:

- Increasing the timeout duration
- Changing the `User-Agent` in the request headers
- Running the script at different times of the day to rule out server load issues

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to load it when using curl ?

Comment: Some websites block access from the IP address range assigned to Amazon EC2 instances. You can test this by logging into your EC2 instance and attempting to access their site (eg `curl www.net-a-porter.com`). Sites tend to block access from EC2 instances to prevent their website from being scraped. Are you sure that `net-a-porter.com` permits what you are doing? Their [Terms & Conditions](https://www.net-a-porter.com/en-au/content/help/terms-and-conditions/) seems to say that content cannot be used for any commercial purpose.